# Prove that two norms are equivalent in the space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\mathbf{P}$ The set of polynomials of degree $\leq$ two, with real coefficients in $[0, 1]$, if $l=ax^2+bx+c$ in $\mathbf{P}$, we define the norms $||l||_{1}=|a|+|b|+|c|$ and $||l||_{\infty}=\max_{x\in[0, 1]}{\{|l(x)|\}}$

Considering that $\mathbf{P}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, i want to prove that these norms are equivalent using this definition of equivalence (for some $k_{1}, k_{2}$ and all $l(x)\in \mathbf{P}$)

$$k_{1}||l||_{1}\leq||l||_{\infty}\leq k_{2}||l||_{1}$$

I began by observing that as $x, a, b, c\in[0, 1]$ then $0\leq x \leq 1$ so multiplying on the inequality we have that $ax^{2}\leq ax \leq a$, $bx \leq b$ and $c\leq c$ so $ax^{2}+bx+c \leq a+b+c$ and $|ax^{2}+bx+c| \leq |a+b+c| \leq |a|+|b|+|c|$, this means $|l(x)| \leq ||l||_{1}$.

Since the maximum of a set always belongs to itself, then there exists $x_{0}$ such that $||l(x)||_{\infty}=|l(x_{0})|\leq||l(x_{0})||_{1}$, and for that value of $x_{0}$ you would have one of the inequalities (taking $k_{2}=1)$.

That said can it work? and any suggestions for the other inequality? appreciate it!

Comment: I'm guessing you want to find a concrete $k_1$ and a concrete $k_2$ without just relying on the fact that norms are equivalent on a vector space of finite dimension, right? By the way, for norms I'd advise using `\| thing \|` rather than double bars, but that's just a nitpick.

Comment: I think your reasoning for how you know there exists $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $\|l(x)\|_\infty = |l(x_0)|$ is circular. You said you know such an $x_0$ exists because it's a maximum. But *you* defined it to be the maximum without first giving a reason why you know the set has a maximum. 

You can say you know the maximum exists (when you define $\|\cdot\|_\infty$) by saying it's a continuous function on a compact domain.

Comment: @BrunoB That's right, the idea is to find these constants, although what could be a basis to show that these spaces are of finite dimension?

Comment: Well, $(x^2, x, 1)$ would be a basis. In general, a vector space of polynomials with bounded degree will always have finite dimension, as it would be a vector subspace of the set of polynomials of degree the maximal degree found in your subspace, which has finite dimension.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious?  How can $\mathbf{P}$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$ if the coefficients are restricted to $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find $p_0,p_1,p_2\in {\bf P}$ such that for $r,s\in \{0,1,2\}$,

$$\int_0^1 p_r(x)x^s dx=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & : r=s, \\ 0 & : r\neq s.\end{array}\right.$$ This will take a little linear algebra.

Then for $l(x)=\sum_{s=0}^2 a_sx^s$ and $r\in \{0,1,2\}$,  you have $$|a_r|=\Bigl|\int_0^1 p_r(x)l(x)dx\Bigr| \leqslant \int_0^1 |p_r(x)||l(x)|dx \leqslant \int_0^1 \|p_r\|_\infty \|l\|_\infty=\|p_r\|_\infty\|l\|_\infty.$$ Therefore $$\|l\|_1 \leqslant |a_0|+|a_1|+|a_2|\leqslant 3\max_{r\in \{0,1,2\}} |a_r| \leqslant  \Bigl(3\max_{r\in \{0,1,2\}}\|p_r\|_\infty\Bigr)\|l\|_\infty.$$

If you want an exact value of the constant, you'll have to find an upper bound on $\max_{r\in \{0,1,2\}} \|p_r\|_\infty$ (which is by no means the best possible constant), but in order to solve the problem without knowing the exact value of the constant, it is enough to know that this maximum is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for a polynomial $p(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ we have
$$\begin{cases} p(1) = a+b+c,\\ p\left(\frac12\right) = \frac14 a + \frac12 b + c, \\ p(0) = c.\end{cases}$$
By solving this $3\times 3$ linear system for the unknowns $a,b,c$ we obtain the relations
$$\begin{cases} a = 2p(1)-4p\left(\frac12\right)+2p(0),\\ b = -p(1)+4p\left(\frac12\right)-3p(0), \\ c = p(0).\end{cases}$$
We can now use the triangle inequality to easily bound
$$|a| \le 2|p(1)|+4\left|p\left(\frac12\right)\right|+2|p(0)| \le 8\|p\|_\infty,$$
$$|b| \le |p(1)|+4\left|p\left(\frac12\right)\right|+3|p(0)| \le 8\|p\|_\infty,$$
$$|c| = |p(0)| \le \|p\|_\infty$$
so by summing up we obtain
$$\|p\|_1 = |a|+|b|+|c| \le 17\|p\|_\infty.$$
To show that this is the optimal bound, we can consider the polynomial $p(x) = x^2-x+\frac18$ which satisfies
$$\|p\|_1 = 1+1+\frac18 = \frac{17}8, \qquad \|p\|_\infty = |p(1)| = \left|p\left(\frac12\right)\right| = |p(0)| = \frac18.$$